# python3-qt4 discards non-ascii characters from unicode strings in QApplication contructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to port a PyQt based application to Python 3. If I initialize QApplication with sys.argv, QApplication.arguments() returns those arguments without non-ascii characters. The workaround is to encode arguments as bytes. But it's hard for me to believe that it's the best approach. Why cannot PyQt just accept unicode strings? Maybe some locale settings need to be tweaked?

Example code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

args = ["test", "tsch\u00fcss", "tsch\u00fcss".encode("utf-8")]
print("args:", args)
qapp = QApplication(args)
qargs = qapp.arguments()
print("qargs:", qargs)
```

Output:

```
args: ['test', 'tschüss', b'tsch\xc3\xbcss']
qargs: ['test', 'tschss', 'tschüss']
```

Things that make no difference:

```
import sip
sip.setapi("QString", 2)

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
```

Ubuntu 14.10, python3-pyqt4 4.11.2+dfsg-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in PyQt, as it is handled correctly by PySide.

And there seems no reason why the args can't be properly encoded before being passed to the application constructor:

```
>>> import os
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> args = ['føø', 'bær']
>>> app = QtCore.QCoreApplication([os.fsencode(arg) for arg in args])
>>> app.arguments()
['føø', 'bær']
```

If you want to see this get fixed, please report it on the [PyQt Mailing List](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).

Comment: I've just reported the bug. As for PySide, it's not much better. In Python 3, the bytes arguments are completely discarded. In Python 2, unicode arguments make the interpreter crash.

Comment: `os.fsencode` is not available in Python 2. I want code that works in Python 2 and 3 without conditionals.

Comment: @proski. Using PySide-1.2.2 and Python 3 with unicode works fine. It's not a bug that unicode doesn't work with Python 2 (for either PySide or PyQt4), since bytes should always be the only valid input. And for that same reason, the lack of `os.fsencode` in Python 2 is irrelevant. If you want compatiblity between Python 2 and 3, you will have to deal with that issue yourself. The only bug here is that PyQt does not handle unicode strings correctly with Python 3.

Comment: Be liberal at what you accept or complain loudly. Crashing Python and discarding data don't fit that pattern. Not going to start a long discussion here, I posted my observations to the PySide mailing list.

Comment: @proski. Those sentiments may apply to Python, but it's not safe to assume they will also apply to PyQt/PySide. There are numerous ways to shoot yourself in the foot if you don't take the necessary precautions. Ultimately, you are mostly dealing with a C++ library, and so there's not always the same level of hand-holding that you might expect from Python. So, sometimes, the only realistic remedy is simply: "don't do that".

Comment: @proski Why posting the observations to the PySide mailing list. Shouldn't the error be with PyQt? I can confirm that PySide on Python 3 here deals with unicode as it should without any further processing necessary.

Comment: @Trilarion Good point. There are errors on both sides and I reported both of them.